# Keras Embedding ,where is the "weights" argument?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have seen such kind of code as follow:

```
embed_word = Embedding(params['word_voc_size'], params['embed_dim'], weights=[word_embed_matrix], input_length = params['word_max_size']
                        , trainable=False, mask_zero=True)
```

When I look up the document in Keras website [https://faroit.github.io/keras-docs/2.1.5/layers/embeddings/][1]

I didnt see weights argument,

```
keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim, output_dim, embeddings_initializer='uniform', embeddings_regularizer=None, activity_regularizer=None, embeddings_constraint=None, mask_zero=False, input_length=None)
```

So I am confused,why we can use the argument weights which was not defined the in Keras document?

My keras version is 2.1.5. Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 14):

Keras' `Embedding` layer subclasses the `Layer` class (every Keras layer does this). The `weights` attribute is implemented in this base class, so every subclass will allow to set this attribute through a `weights` argument. This is also why you won't find it back in the documentation or the implementation of the `Embedding` layer itself.

You can check the base layer implementation [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/base_layer.py) (Ctrl + F for 'weight').

Comment: While this is technically true, this cannot be used to initialize the embedding weights anymore, see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14392