# How to fine-tune pre-trained embeddings in embedding layer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

How can I fine tune pre-trained embeddings in embedding layer in tf.keras?

```
# embedding layer with pre trained weights
embedding_layer = layers.Embedding(
    input_dim=self.vocab_size + 2,
    output_dim=self.emb_size,
    embeddings_initializer=initializers.Constant(embedding_matrix),
    mask_zero=mask_zero,
    trainable=False
)
```

If I just change `trainable = True` will it fine tune the pre-trained embeddings that I have? Or should I also have to remove `initializers.Constant` as initializer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the following [answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/17557/how-to-user-kerass-embedding-layer-properly):

When setting the `trainable` to `true` you let the embedding layer to fine-tune.

Setting the `embeddings_initializer` will contradict the `trained` flag. you should either don't set it to constant, or you can just set the weights with the `embedding_matrix`. You can refer to the following links:

1. [setting the weights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53417537/keras-initialize-large-embeddings-layer-with-pretrained-embeddings)
2. [meaning of `constat`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/initializers/Constant)

Regarding to your comment where is the `weights` refer to the following link: [Keras Embedding ,where is the "weights" argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53627251/keras-embedding-where-is-the-weights-argument/53628626)

Comment: In the official docs, I couldn't find a weights parameter io embedding layer? Am I missing something here

Comment: Also I am bit confused, are word embeddings called as weights?

Comment: It’s inherit it from the base class, it’s “hidden” in the **kwargs. You could also can’t find name but it exist

Comment: Just one more doubt, are work embeddings is called as weights? Because we are literally passing word embedding matrix to weights parameter right?

Comment: @user_12 I don’t understand the question, should you mind to elaborate. Maybe the following will help https://blog.keras.io/using-pre-trained-word-embeddings-in-a-keras-model.html

Comment: Are word embeddings matrix and weights are same? Because you mentioned to use weights parameter in embedding layer and pass embeddings matrix as value. So, I'm bit confused of the terminology. Are weights and embeddings terminology interchangeable used.

Comment: @user_12 Once you have an embedding layer, trained, this matrix can serve as weights. It will be a matrix of numbers, so you can always use them as the starting weights if you wish to

Comment: I think I got it, so you are saying we can use those embeddings as starting weights and fine-tune it.